# Maximizing incomplete likelihood

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes, hierarchical-bayesian, hyperparameter

Given the conditional distribution $p(x|y)$ and the prior of the hidden variables $p(y|\theta)$ with unknown hyper-parameter $\theta$. Now we have observed i.i.d. samples of $x$.

Besides the Bayes and empirical Bayes approach, is it possible to estimate both the hidden variables $y$ and the hyper-parameter $\theta$ directly by maximizing the incomplete likelihood $p(x,y|\theta)$?

From the Bayesian perspective, it is equivalent to finding the joint mode of $p(y,\theta|x)$ given an uninformative flat prior of $\theta$.